# Bluetooth connection fails when try to send command via bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am trying to control a RC car using accelerometer via my own android studio app.

I managed to get the app to work through buttons by calling functions when a button is pressed.

I am trying to do the same with accelerometer by saying id the valus of x is less then this do this and call the function. but I cant connect to bluetooth the second i include my go foward function or andy functions to send the bluetooth command inside the if statement.

If connection is not success "Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again". I keep getting this message

This is the  part of the accelerometer code i have if statements.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // clean current values
    displayCleanValues();
    // display the current x,y,z accelerometer values
    displayCurrentValues();
    // display the max x,y,z accelerometer values
    displayMaxValues();

    // get the change of the x,y,z values of the accelerometer
    deltaX =(lastX - event.values[0]);
    deltaY = (lastY - event.values[1]);
    deltaZ = (lastZ - event.values[2]);

    // if the change is below 2, it is just plain noise
    if (deltaX < 2)
        DownArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        DownArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if ((deltaZ > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaY > vibrateThreshold) || (deltaZ > vibrateThreshold)) {
        v.vibrate(50);
    }

    if (deltaX > -4) {
        UpArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        goForward();
    }

    if (deltaX < -4)
        UpArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    if (deltaX < -7)
        DownArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        goBackward();

    if (deltaX > -7)
        DownArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

}

This is the functions I call which sends the bluetooth command.

```
private void goForward()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("F".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}

private void goBackward()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("B".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Bluetooth code

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            msg("Connected.");
            isBtConnected = true;
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
```

I am doing the same in my button view and it works fine.

```
btnUp.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                btnUp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_arrow_green_up_select);
                goForward();
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                btnUp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_arrow_green_up);
                Stop();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Why it keeps failing?

Comment: So what's the communication type for your data?SPP or BLE?

Comment: I am using HC 06 bluetooth module, which i believe is a BLE. My button mode works just fine. it is only when I try to send the command within the if statement for accelerometer it fails.

Comment: Hi,Sorry I am using SPP.

Answer (score 0):

I did a project for fun, Turn on led when any one shake the android mobile. I used arduino and HC-05 in order to communicate android with LED. I think the problem is you are sending "F" and "8" values through bluetooth in UI thread. so create other thread for sending values through bluetooth.

I am sharing part of my code, I think this would be use full.

```
 mmOutputstream=socket.getOutputStream();


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
        // Shake detection
        float x = mGravity[0];
        float y = mGravity[1];
        float z = mGravity[2];
        int check=0;
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;

        Log.d("TAG",data);
    // Make this higher or lower according to how much
            // motion you want to detect
       if(connection){
           if(mAccel<-2.0f)
           {
               check=10;
           }
           if(mAccel>-2.4f){
               check=0;
           }

       new arduinosend().execute(check);
       }
    }

}

class arduinosend extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>
{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            mmOutputstream.write(params[0]);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }





}
```